# Changing Unreadable TensorFlow Debugger (tfdbg) Colors

Tags: tensorflow

I'm running TensorFlow on Windows (long story). When I run the TensorFlow Debugger (tfdbg) on a Windows command prompt using [these directions](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/debugger) the colors on the tfdbg screen are practically unreadable on my monitor.

[image]

I have tried changing the colors on my command prompt but the curses package on tfdbg is changing both the foreground and the background colors on the blue text so that text remains unreadable.

How do I change the tfdbg colors so that I can read the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed problem by fixing broken install of pyreadline and changing:

```
sess = debug.LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession(sess)
```

to:

```
sess = debug.LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession(sess, ui_type="readline")
```